# "undefined variable" notice on my wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm getting the following notice on my wordpress page:

> Notice: Undefined variable: class in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas05_data03/83/2997683/html/wp-content/themes/ccl-label/healthcare.php on line 28

Here is line 28. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this line?

```
<body <?php body_class($class); ?> >
```

Comment: Seems pretty clear that `$class` is undefined, no?

Comment: Sounds like there is an error in the code above line 28. Can you post the full PHP file to view?